# PHP Error Reporting stopped working

Tags: php, apache, error-reporting

What are the possible reasons that my php error reporting would stop displaying to the browser? I must have changed something somewhere, but for the life of me I cant figure it out.

I have error_reporting set to E_ALL in a php script, doesnt seem to be anything in my php.ini or .htaccess that would be stopping it from displaying as well.

Where else can this be happening?

Comment: `php_info()` will specify the "local" setting for error_reporting. If that's still turned on, and you don't get any output, check which log file the error output should be going to.

Comment: in php_info(), it says
error_reporting (local value) 30719

Comment: Check `display_errors` (show error msgs in client output) and `log_errors` (log error msgs to to file) and `error_log` (file to log errors to).

Comment: try putting error_reporting(1); on top of your page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also `display_errors` which might be disabled. http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Or use this as workaround for testing if any errors would come up:

```
set_error_handler("var_dump");
```